# Understanding Backbone.js concepts

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I am trying to learn Backbone.js.
In my app which uses Backbone with RequireJS, I have the following code;

```
define([
    'base/BaseView',
    'model/BaseModel',
    ], function(BaseView, 
        BaseModel){
        var myView = BaseView.extend({
            initialize: function() {
                this.Summary = new resultSummary({
                    scenId : this.options.scenario.get("scenId")
                });
            },
            renderCount : function(){
                var self = this;
                var currentStatus = self.model.get("myStatus");
            }
            render: function () {
            var self = this;
            var gridItems = [];
            gridItems.push({
                    id: "company.status", 
                    text: "Status",
                    width: "200px",
                    renderer: function() {
                        var partnerStatus = this.company.get("status");
                    }
            });     
            }
        }
    });
```

I am not very clear with a few concepts;

1. What exactly would "this" represent when we say var self = this (I would like to understand this as a general question as well meaning when we use "this" anywhere in JS code)
2. Does "this" change if we are inside initialize Vs when we are in renderCount Vs when we are in "render" in the above code?
3. For the code "this.company.get("status")", what exactly does this.company represent? Is that referring to model ?

Comment: It is actually just a representation of the actual working code..

Comment: This question has more to do with javascript concepts than backbone.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking about closure?

we assign

```
var self = this;
```

so we can retain the scope of the class inside a nested function. on this case:

```
renderer: function() {
                    var partnerStatus = this.company.get("status");
                }
```

Here's a great read: ["Closures - JavaScript | MDN"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

Answer (score 2):

I probably won't be able to answer all the questions, since code in question is probably copied from larger code base.

1. Why do we use var self = this; and what exactly would this represent when the above code is executed ?

*var self = this;* is used to avoid scoping problems. Sometimes, when you use callbacks, *this* might change to some other object. Code mentioned in question doesn't benefit from it in any way *this* could be used directly.

Example when it is usefull - lets say, we need to listen to changes in model, and we want to attach handler in initialize method and call some logic from view on changes:

```
// view code
initialize: function() {
    console.log(this); // 'this' points to view
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change", function() {
        console.log(this); // 'this' points to model
        // calling 'this.someLogic();' would throw exception
    });
},

someLogic: function() {
    // ..
}
```

To avoid problem described in first example, you need to store 'this' from view context in some other variable (don't have to be named self).

Rewritten example:

```
// view code
initialize: function() {
    console.log(this); // 'this' points to view
    var self = this; // store this into variable that will won't be changed in different scope
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change", function() {
        console.log(this); // 'this' points to model
        console.log(self); // 'self' points to view
        self.someLogic(); // won't throw
    });
},

someLogic: function() {
    // ..
}
```

I recommend you to check how closures in JavaScript work. It is usefull not only for Backbone, but for JavaScript development in general.

1. Does "this" change if we are inside initialize Vs when we are in renderCount Vs when we are in "render" in the above code?

No, Backbone will point 'this' to view object, which contains those methodd.

1. For the code "this.company.get("status")", what exactly does this.company represent? Is that referring to model ?

No idea really, I can only guess, that it is some property from *BaseView*